# How to return a file from a Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, pdf

I have a standard WCF (.svc) service that usually speaks JSON. I need to create a method to return a PDF file.

I can do this (theoretically, haven't tried it)

```
public Byte[] GetDocument(string DocumentName)
{
  string strdocPath;
  strdocPath = "C:\\DocumentDirectory\\" + DocumentName;

  FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
  int len = (int)objfilestream.Length;          
  Byte[] documentcontents  = new Byte[len];
  objfilestream.Read(documentcontents,0,len);
  objfilestream.Close();

  return documentcontents;  
}
```

But I need to specify the file name, which I am not sure how to do in this context.

In a regular asp.net mvc, I would do this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.FileName + "\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.FileSize.ToString());
Response.OutputStream.Write(file.Bytes, 0, file.Bytes.Length);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

but the Response object doesn't seem to be around in an WCF project.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Return `Stream`. I think, you can use *OperationContext* or *WebOperationContext* to set the headers.

Answer (score 3):

I am using it like this:

```
string agent = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["User-Agent"];

if (agent.Contains("MSIE") == false)
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"{0}\"".Fill(attachment.Filename));
}
else
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"{0}\"".Fill(attachment.Filename));
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("X-Download-Options", "noopen");
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
}

return new MemoryStream(attachment.Data);
```